# Why is my Telerik Grid an empty square?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to learn the basics of Telerik's RadGrid.

I am trying to place an empty grid on a page with just column headers.  With the following code, just an empty, white rectangle appears instead.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Windows7" >
  <MasterTableView>
      <Columns>   
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="TextTitle" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" UniqueName="NamePINcolumn" />
      </Columns>        
  </MasterTableView>
```

Currently I don't have any data to supply the table, I just want to hard code some data into the table for demo purposes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **DataField** for [GridBoundColumn](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html). Otherwise, Grid doesn't know what field to display.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="xxx " ... />
```

### Update: to display demo data

[image]

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <mastertableview datakeynames="Id">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" 
                UniqueName="Id" HeaderText="Id"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" 
                UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
        </Columns>
    </mastertableview>
</telerik:RadGrid>

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        var users = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Jon"},
            new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Marry"}
        };
        RadGrid1.DataSource = users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I don't have any data to supply the table, I just want to hard code some data into the table for demo purposes. Is this possible?